# Механизм определения слова без учета языка раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: java, поиск, полнотекстовый-поиск, solr

Мне нужно написать метод, который будет распознавать введенное слово, не смотря на язык клавиатуры. В основном я использую русскую(РУ) и английскую(США) раскаладку. Мне нужно чтобы при вводе слов на русском языке с использованием английской клавиатуры система понимала, что я ввожу русское слово, но без переключения на русскую клавиатуру, и наоборот, чтобы распознавала английские слова введенные без переключения на английскую клавиатуру. Например, как это сделано в ГУГЛ поиске. Если ввести английское слово **milk**, оно выдаст **milk**. Если ввести русское слово **молоко** таким образом - **vjkjrj**(англо-русская клавиатура) - он мне выдаст результат с русским словом **молоко**.

Например:

1. молоко vjkjrj
2. екуу tree
3. абдула f,lekf
4. g.ht пюре
5. i.go шюпо

С чего начать? Возможно, имеются некоторые библиотеки готовые?

Данные подтягиваются через Solr(с использованием полнотекстового поиска).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения подобной задачи можно считать [расстояние Дамерау - Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83_%E2%80%94_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) между введенным словом и словами из заранее подготовленных словарей для разных языков.
Возможно, с некоторыми ограничениями, если необходимо.

Примерный алгоритм:

1. Получаем на вход от пользователя слово. Допустим, 'руддщ' (hello)
2. Осуществляем поиск данного слова в словаре языка, соответствующего раскладке. Если не находим - переходим к следующему шагу.
3. Осуществляем преобразование слова во все другие раскладки. В нашем случае, 'руддщ' -> 'hello'.
4. Считаем расстояние Дамерау-Левенштейна и выбираем то слово, расстояние до которого является наименьшим. В случае равенства, отдаем предпочтение тому языку, раскладка которого установлена.